# Linear fit with errors on x and y

Tags: python, linear-regression, least-squares

Using python, I am trying to find the equation of a line that best fits my data. However, I have errors on the x and y data points. Note that my errors are not symmetric. Here is what my data points look like:

```
   x    x_upper_err    x_lower_err    y        y_upper_err    y_lower_err
-0.120  0.280           0.280       0.074484    0.000140    -0.000077
 0.210  0.170           0.270       0.091828    0.000414    -0.001600
-0.280  0.300           0.300       0.041035    0.002209    -0.000771
```

I have tried to use the `kmpfit` package but this package assumes that my errors follow a Gaussian distribution. http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#fitting-data-when-both-variables-have-uncertainties

Is there another method to do it? I came across the ODR (Orthogonal Distance Regression) method, however this method also takes into account that the errors are normally distributed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

In order to test if the errors on the data are normally distributed, I did a `Q-Q plot`. Here are my results:

`Q-Q plot of independent variable`
[image: Q-Q plot of independent variable]

`Q-Q plot of dependent variable`

[image: Q-Q plot of dependent variable]

I can assume that my `independent` variables are `normally distributed`, but I cannot assume this for my `dependent` errors.

**Question 1:** Knowing that my `dependent errors` are not normally distributed, what should the next step be?

**Question 2:** Is it feasible to use ODR to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you so sure your residuals are not normally distributed? One way to check for this assumption is to use a [Q-Q plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot). From a pragmatic perspective, most people will just look at a scatterplot of their data to see whether residuals are normally distributed. Often a violation of this assumption is not critical, but it depends on what you're trying to do.

Using orthogonal distance regression, as opposed to ordinary least squares (which is presumably what you are using) doesn't do anything to fix the problem. You may get better answers on stats.stackexchange.com, and in particular [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100214/assumptions-of-linear-models-and-what-to-do-if-the-residuals-are-not-normally-di) might help you.

Comment: 1) It's hard to make anything of your residuals Q-Q plot because you have two very extreme outliers. You should filter your data for outliers prior to regression, regardless of what else you choose to do. 2) No, I still don't see how ODR would help you.

Comment: I guess I will use Bayesian Statistics to calculate the posterior distribution.